# Tensorflow: get NaN in “moving_variance“ in one layer when using batch_norm function

Tags: tensorflow

**Problem:**

After training a classification model using [SE_Inception_resnet_v2](https://github.com/taki0112/SENet-Tensorflow/blob/master/SE_Inception_resnet_v2.py), I haved used a unseen image for the prediction. However, the results are always the same. For instance, the result is *logits = [.1,.2,.3]* all the time.

By debugging the code, I found that the **values normalized by using tensoflow's batch_norm function are all zeros** in one particular layer, other layers using the batch_norm function are still fine which output normalized input values. In my case, it's in the *Reduction_B/cond/Merge:0* node that output all zero values.

More, I checked the input data and parameters for batch_norm function on that particular layer. The input data are fine, however, the parameter **moving_variance are NaN** but moving_mean are fine. And interestingly, previous **moving_variance** updates are also fine.

I think this is the cause of my problem, could anyone explain what might be the cause, how could I solve it? Thanks

Comment: A variance of `nan` indicates your input at some point was likely all the same... but even then, tensorflow's batch_norm implementation has `variance_epsilon` for precisely this reason. As for solving the issue... `moving_variance` shouldn't be used in training mode, so can you test the behaviour in training mode (for your prediction image)? You may have had a single dud image at some point which set values to NaN, and you may just need to reset these moving average values (which will retrain themselves very quickly.)

Comment: Solved, posted solution below. Although it's not something wrong with my input data, but you show me the right direction to check. Thanks a lot, Jack!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved now. The solution is that the **size of batch must be greater than 1**. I will post two cases below to show one is working and the other other is not for my case.

**Case 1: (Failed)**

Number of training samples: 10

 Batch size: 1

 Iteration: 10

**Case 2: (Success)**

Number of training samples: 10

 Batch size: 2

 Iteration: 5

Comment: I'm also getting NaN in the moving average of a BatchNormalization layer with input (None, 1, 1, 512), for which I am providing a batch of 1 input. It has no effect on prediction if I'm using tensorflow for python, but when saving the model and trying to use it from tensorflowjs, all outputs become NaN. Still need to figure out how to overcome this.